# Session is not setting quickly

Tags: reactjs, session

Session does not set quickly in react.

```
function setsession (){
setSession({ ...session, ...result }); //here is session is set
console.log(session) // session does not have the data
}
```

again i trigger function to set sesison
when i console the old result data is now stored in session.

Here is the whole code - https://jsfiddle.net/0ksw5zfh/

Comment: It looks like setsession is taking much time to set data into session.
Is their any way i can check if setsession is executed ? Or any other alternative solution ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?